# No Data in JSON Array - BeautifulSoup and Python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The script I have below keeps returning an empty array when I try to write the contents to a JSON file.  There are no errors that pop up when the script in run.  It does not print anything in the terminal either.  I have some similar scripts for other websites that are working perfectly.  Here is my code.  Thanks in advance.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import json

openstax = 'https://cnx.org'

#opening up connection and grabbing page
uClient = urlopen(openstax)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs info for each textbook
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"book"})

data = []
for container in containers:
   item = {}
   item['type'] = "Textbook"
   item['title'] = container.h3.a.text
   data.append(item)
   print(item['title']) 

with open("./json/openstax.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    json.dump(data, writeJSON, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Have you done a view page source on cnx.org yet and searched for divs where class="book"? Is cnx.org where you're actually going, or is that filler? Because I don't see any divs where class="book" (I don't see any ids, or anything, searching for "book" returns nothing.

Comment: I did inspect and got the class="book." I do see where the page source doesn't have this class.

Comment: The answer from dethos discusses why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you are fetching (defined in the `openstax` variable) is generated on the client side using `javascript`. So the final html isn't present on the response to the request you make using your code.

Because of this, when you search `page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"book"})`, it isn't returning any elements, which in turn explains the json file being an empty array.

As it is stated on the returned `html` of that page, in the `noscript` element, you should try using the `http://legacy.cnx.org/content` url if you don't want use the `javascript` rendered webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The content of that page generates dynamically so you can't grab them with the way you tried above. You need to use any browser simulator or try this [URL](https://archive.cnx.org/extras) to fetch the result. The latter is much more efficient and easy to deal with. Give it a go.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://archive.cnx.org/extras')
for item in r.json()['featuredLinks']:
    print(item['title'])
```

Result:

```
Applied Probability
Understanding Basic Music Theory
Programming Fundamentals - A Modular Structured Approach using C++
Advanced Algebra II: Conceptual Explanations
Flowering Light: Kabbalistic Mysticism and the Art of Elliot R. Wolfson
Hearing Harmony: What is Harmony?
```